# Error "Not found: Dataset *****:dataform was not found in location US." while repository located in EU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dataform, google-bigquery-dataform

I am currently working with a SQL workflow using Dataform. Within this workflow, I have declared certain tables and established dependencies among them. Everything is functioning as expected in this regard. However, I encountered an issue when attempting to create a table that depends on other tables which have not been declared explicitly.

The problem arises from the fact that the query doesn't compile due to the error message:

> Not found: Dataset *****:dataform was not found in location US

Even though my repository is configured in the EU.

For illustration, here's an example:

simple_table

```
config {
  type: "table",
  description: ""
  }
SELECT 1 AS number
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS number
```

dependent_table

```
config {
  type: "table",
  description: ""
}
SELECT * FROM ${ref("simple_table")}
```

I tried to change the repository location, it didn't work.

Comment: What location is the dataform project in? You can find this under the settings tab in GCP

Comment: I have the same issue. My dataform repo is in europe-west6, dataform workspace in europe-west6, source table dataset in europe-west6, target table in a dataset in europe-west6, but I get an error that says the dataset wasn't found in location EU. ;-(

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine data from multiple regions, so one of the tables is in the US, and one is in the EU, or they're all in the US and your project is set to EU. As mentioned above, changing the location in `dataform.json` will fix this.

If you're dealing with data across different regions, the way I've resolved this in the past is to set up a daily data transfer that moves the data I need to the primary region, then use that as your source.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `dataform.json` in your project root. In my case there was

```
  "defaultLocation": "EU"
```

that was causing the same issue. In your case, "US" is probably set there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running with the Dataform CLI then it's likely that your credentials are locked to that region. When you initialise the credentials with `dataform init-creds bigquery`, you are asked to choose between

```
[1] US (default)
[2] EU
[3] other
```

Chances are that you selected the default option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).